# literal_eval returns malformed string given a string without quote

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval, literals

I try to convert a string containing two lists using literal_eval as shown below.

```
from ast import literal_eval
literal_eval('[[ba], [38]]')
```

However I got this error

```
raise ValueError('malformed string')
```

Is it because 'ba' is not converted to string? How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes. Fix is add quotes manually.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this question. So I gave a counter-upvote. Now that the solution is clear though, perhaps the title could be changed to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because that's not a valid set of Python literals you're asking it to eval. The string needs to be quoted, like so:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
literal_eval('[["ba"], [38]]')
```

Then you will get the correct result:

```py
[['ba'], [38]]
```

Comment: "that's not valid Python" - it is, because `ast.parse('[[ba], [38]]')` doesn't raise any exceptions.

Comment: It's parsable Python, assuming `ba` is a name (variable), but not legit  for Python literals. `ast.parse()` and `ast.literal_eval()` follow different parts of the Python grammar. The latter is strictly for literals, and abides by literals-only rules, whereas the former is not / does not. Tweaked the answer wording to make that clearer.

Comment: Yep, you're right. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) says "The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`". So, it's not a valid literal, then.